# I need help writing a php file to redirect a html request.

Tags: php, html

This is a tricky problem as it is multi layered, but I'm sure there will be folks who can help me.

Basically, I have a html snippet on my website which requires a URL to execute. Instead of just writing the URL in the space, I would like it to get the contents of a text file on my server, but also add the contents of another.

here is the HTML snippet with the line which needs the text on the 4th line:

```
1## <script type="text/javascript" src="mrp.js"></script>
2## <script type="text/javascript">
3## MRP.insert({
4## 'url':'TEXT FROM FILES HERE',
5## 'codec':'mp3',
6## 'volume':65,
7## 'autoplay':false,
8## 'buffering':5,
9## 'title':'Radio Zaum',
10## 'welcome':'WELCOME TO...',
11## 'bgcolor':'#FFFFFF',
12## 'skin':'simple-gray',
13## 'width':300,
14## 'height':122
15## });
16## </script>
```

I hope someone can help me do this pretty simple, yet frustrating task!
Thanks!!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: see php file_get_content() http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking but when you say

```
"I would like it to get the contents of a text file on my server"
```

i'm guessing you mean to grab contents of a file and insert the text in the js snippet to automate?

Your line of code:

```
2## <script type="text/javascript">
3## MRP.insert({
4## 'url':'TEXT FROM FILES HERE',
```

Possible solution: 
use

```
echo $scrape_file = file_get_contents("the_file.txt or html");
```

The output of the code above will be:
This is a test file with test text.

```
2## <script type="text/javascript">
3## MRP.insert({
4## 'url':'<?=$scrape_file?>',
```

Comment: i STupidly deleted my working player and now can't remember why this made sense to me! please help me out again amazing unimiah! where do i add the `echo $scrape_file = file_get_contents("the_file.txt or html");` function? the actual files are dictionary.txt & port.txt and they are just port information and an ip address which combine to provide the link for the radio feed. as far as i can tell, i just put `<?=$scrape_file?>` where i put `TEXT FROM FILES HERE`

Comment: If you could correct my code, I'd appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use text as a store of data, you should use xml and use the simplexml library that comes standard in the new versions of php.

[W3 schools xml page](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)